# Bluetooth printing in C# windows mobile

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-mobile-6

I have this system ive been working on where in the user has to print in a bluetooth thermal printer after every transaction. Can someone give me a source reference or a sample code for this particular function? he bluetooth printer brand is just generic, most of the sources in the website all have brands particularly Zebra. But i wont be using that since it might be different. any help would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see inTheHand (or 32feet.net) for a framework using Bluetooth.

You need to discover and connect to the BT printer and then use a socket stream to send print commands.

You may also use RegisterDevice with the BT mAC address and then use the provided serial COM port to communicate with the printer.

To be more detailed you need to describe your needs in more details and shorter english sentences.